# creating a shell like program in C

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

I am trying to create a simple c program that takes user input, passes it to underlying shell and return the ouput of the user command. For eg: pwd will give the present working directory.

I want to do this using fork() and exec() in an infinite loop but I am facing two problems:

1. My loop terminates after first run
2. It only takes first argument. 'ls -ltr' will give me the output of 'ls' and not 'ls -ltr'

   ```
   int runit(char*);

   void main() {

   int pid=0;                          
   char command[50];
   while(1)

   {
       int d=0;
       printf("Please enter your command!\n");
       scanf("%s", &command);
       switch (pid = fork()) 
       {
           case 0:                    // a fork returns 0 to the child 
               printf("Child process \n");
               d=runit(command);
               if(d==-1){
               printf("command not found \n");}
               break;

           default:
               wait(5);               // a fork returns a pid to the parent 
               printf("Parent process \n"); 
               break;

           case -1:                   //if something went wrong 
               perror("fork");
               exit(1);

       }
     }                
   }

   int runit(char* command) {                     //executing the command

       char path[50]="/bin/";

       int d = execl(strcat(path,command),command,NULL,NULL);     

       return(d);

   }
   ```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or guide me how to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This input reading

```
scanf("%s", &command);
```

would stop at the first whitespace (unless input failure occurs -- you should check the return value of `scanf()` in any case). So, when you input `ls -ltr`, `command` will have just `ls`. You need to read *lines*. For example, use `fgets()` to read input (and make sure to handle the trailing newline):

```
fgets(command, sizeof command, stdin);
command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0; /* to remove \n if present */
```

And the next problem is that `execl()` takes *multiple* arguments. That means 
this usage:

```
int d = execl(strcat(path,command),command,NULL,NULL);
```

is broken. You need to split the input command into multiple strings and pass each arguments to `execl()`. A better option to store the individual strings in an array and use `execv()` instead.

Another thing you need to be aware of is `exec*()` family functions do *not* return on success. So, the return code check isn't very useful - instead you can just use `perror()` to know why it failed if it failed.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. I changed from scanf to gets and modified execl() command and it worked. It works with execv() as well. But which one is better? I prefer execl() just because of the simplicity over execv()

Comment: There's no "better" between execl and execv - they just differ in their arguments. So, use whichever is convenient for your use case.